# Fixed the changes

Tags: apt, upgrade, gnome-terminal, system-settings, apt-listchanges

I have changed everything like Ubuntu settings logo, etc/apt/sources.list file's details , screenfetch/neofetch logo or even Ubuntu boot logo,login screen logo... Everything via customize terminal file changes....

But when i ,
upgrade Ubuntu system (sudo apt upgrade), my all custom changes gone from machine.i also see, when it upgrading system, it's started setting-up all thing like my custom changes , which i does not want.

Now ,

1. What should i do , if i upgrade my Ubuntu system , but my changes will not gone ?
2. What updates does really needed for Ubuntu system.

Comment: There is not enough information to attempt to answer this question. This question needs more focus and we need details. We can't really guess what you mean by *"I have changed everything"*. Please edit your question and include more details and specifics. The more that you changed, and the more that is wrong, the more information we will need to understand the situation sufficiently to offer assistance.

Comment: Include the version and flavor of Ubuntu you are using. Describe the changes: tell us exactly what you changed and how you did it. Describe the steps needed to reproduce the problem, and then describe the problem to us so that we can understand what exactly is wrong.